# Rsync from MacOS to Synology NAS: "@ERROR: host is denied to login"

Tags: mac-osx, rsync, network-attached-storage, synology

I'm using a Synology S420j (running DSM 6.2.4-25556) to backup files from my Mac (Monterey v12.1) using the following command:

```
rsync -avz --backup rsync-user@nas.local::backups/
```

This has previously worked, but I've been changing a few things recently and now I'm getting this error:

```
@ERROR: host is denied to login
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(1402) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Posting this here because I didn't get any results searching the Internet.)

https://serverfault.com/a/564472/31465 gave me a hint that there might be a feature within Synology related to this.  And it turns out that there is - under `Control Panel`, `Security`, `Account`, `Auto Block`.

Simply disabling this option fixed the issue I was having with rsync.